# Make the User.Identity include the email address from the access token payload

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core, openid-connect, openiddict

We are using OAuth via introspection to validate access tokens.

```
app.UseOAuthIntrospection(options =>
{
    options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
    options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
    options.Authority = "http://localhost:12345/";
    options.Audiences.Add("ResourceServer01");
    options.ClientId = "ResourceServer01";
    options.ClientSecret = "secret_secret_secret";
});
```

This works, mostly.

The Authorization Server response at `connect/introspect` is good.

```
{
  "active": true,
  "iss": "http://localhost:12345/",
  "sub": "797264b3-194c-483f-08fb-08d3cbab9158",
  "scope": "openid email roles",
  "iat": 1471998289,
  "nbf": 1471998289,
  "exp": 1472000089,
  "jti": "274cbb7f-9412-4d69-8c02-ca6a500b4a36",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "aud": [
    "ResourceServer01",
    "ResourceServer02"
  ],
  "email": "shaun@bigfont.ca",
  "AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp": "4956a5c3-9efd-4f51-9746-43a187698e1e"
}
```

A request to the resource server gets past the `Authorize` attribute. This is also good.

```
[Authorize(ActiveAuthenticationSchemes = OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[HttpGet("message")]
public IActionResult GetMessage() {
    var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    if (identity == null) {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    return Json(User);
}
```

The `User` though, does not contain the `sub` nor the `email` properties. It just looks like this:

```
{
    "claims": [
        {
            "issuer": "LOCAL AUTHORITY",
            "originalIssuer": "LOCAL AUTHORITY",
            "properties": {},
            "subject": {
                "authenticationType": "Bearer",
                "isAuthenticated": true,
                "actor": null,
                "bootstrapContext": null,
                "claims": []
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can we configure our resource server to include the `sub` and `email` properties in the claims?

Here is [our code on GitHub](https://github.com/shaunluttin/openiddict-samples/tree/spa-sample/samples/ImplicitFlow/ResourceServer01).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claims are likely there (if they're not, it's a bug in the introspection middleware), but JSON.NET is not very good at serializing `Claim`/`ClaimsIdentity`/`ClaimsPrincipal`, probably because these types have circular references (e.g `Claim.Subject` / `ClaimsIdentity.Claims`).

Try using `User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value` and `User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value`/ to confirm the subject identifier and the email address are there.

If it works, consider returning a projection of your claims instead of a `ClaimsPrincipal` instance:

```
return Json(
    from claim in User.Claims 
    select new { claim.Type, claim.Value }
);
```

Here is a screenshot the `User` in the Debug window.

[image: Visual Studio Code Debug Window showing the User]